# How to create a composer package for a Nova Resource

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, laravel-nova

I am building a Nova Page Builder for our company but am new to creating composer packages. Here is what I have as far as files:

- Models / Page.php (model)
- Nova / Pages.php (handles fields for the model)
- Migration file to build "pages" table
- Requires other composer packages for things like nova-tabs, nova-menu, nova-flexible-fields.

I have this all working in a Nova project but we are wanting to turn this into a composer package that can be installed in other projects. I can think of 3 ways to do this.

1. Create a custom Nova tool (I don't want to have to do all of this unless necessary, creating custom Vue components for default Nova behavior seems like overkill)
2. Publish the above files to the app/database directories using Composer and run the migrations
3. Somehow link the vendor/ files for this package to the local app instance? I'm not even sure if this doable.

It would be nice if we could just include a service provider and it would all work, is that possible without creating a custom Nova tool?

Any advice on which route to go down?

Comment: Why you want to reinvent wheel? There is some packages in novapackages.com
For example you can look at 
https://novapackages.com/packages/optimistdigital/nova-page-manager source code